# Cocoapods: Error when adding Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios, cocoapods-1.1.1

I'm following instructions from this [url](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) in order to install Google Maps SDK for iOS.

I'm getting an error when running `pod update` using version 1.1.1.

`[!] The 'Pods-[Target Name]' target has frameworks with conflicting names: googlemapsbase.framework and googleplaces.framework.`

Has anyone got around this issue?

**EDIT:**

Here's the Podfile I'm using.

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'Woof' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'TextAttributes', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'Moya'
  pod 'Moya-ObjectMapper', '2.3.1'
  pod 'ObjectMapper', '2.2.6'
  pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 8.0'
  pod 'DateTools'
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 3.2'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'Stripe', '10.2.0'
  pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 2.1' #might change
  pod 'QuickBlox'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'Cosmos'
  pod 'JTAppleCalendar', '~> 7.0.2'
  pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
  pod 'ImageSlideshow'
  pod 'ImageSlideshow/SDWebImage'
  pod 'Eureka'
  pod 'ImageRow'
  pod 'SuggestionRow'
  pod 'GooglePlacesRow'
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'BSImagePicker'
  pod 'OnboardingKit'
  pod 'DZNSegmentedControl'
  pod 'ReadMoreTextView'
  pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'MGSwipeTableCell'
  pod 'KMPlaceholderTextView', '~> 1.3.0'
  pod 'TTRangeSlider'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'

  target 'WoofTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'WoofUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

**EDIT 2:**

It seems the `GooglePlacesRow` library is already importing Google Maps and Google Places. This issue gets solved deleting last two lines:

```
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
```

Comment: Can you show your entire podifle?

Comment: @ChrisAllwein added

Answer (score 0):

(As of 2017/07/23)  I think this might be caused by the fact that GooglePlacesRow has GooglePlaces 2.0.1 as a dependency but the current version (that you're also including) is 2.3.1.  I would try removing the `pod 'GooglePlaces'` line from your podfile.  It should still get installed as a dependency of GooglePlacesRow.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I thought that was the issue. I removed it and I still get `The 'Pods-[target name]' target has frameworks with conflicting names: googlemapsbase.framework.`

Comment: Most likely, both GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces use the googlemapsbase.framework.  Try replacing the GoogleMaps line with `GoogleMaps , '~> 2.0.1'`.  Or, it might be able to use both GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces via CocoaPods, and just include GooglePlacesRow by copying the code directly into your project.

Comment: Yes, the library is already importing the Google Maps library. I think the correct response is to delete both lines.